# Requesting .net server to response, while its busy

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, multithreading, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to request a .NET server for an XHR request, while it is busy with another task?
Basically, I am working on an e-commerce application, that generates invoices of purchases once at a time, that may be weekly, monthly etc. So, while in process to generate the invoices a lot of calculations, and database reads and writes are done on the server side, but the user can only wait for the complete process to finish at once without knowing the progress made by the server. As per the project's requirement, the application can be generating thousands of invoices at a time, so I guess that'll take a lot of time.

So, I was thinking that, is it possible for me to write a code in ASP.NET, C# & jQuery, for requesting an XHR from the server while it is busy with generating invoices, so as to know the progress made by the server.

The process may be like:

1. User selects the criteria for Invoice generation on the screen and clicks **Generate Invoice** button.
2. The server gets the requests and makes a initial read operation on the database so as to return the number of records or invoices to be generated, and simultaneously starts generating invoices.
3. The output of that `Read()`, is sent to the Client System, and on client's side, a modal pop starts to show a progress bar telling the number of records to be processed as well as those completed processes.

As a server cannot send a response by itself without the client initiating with a request to do so, I guess the client may be sending XHR's every 10-20 seconds so as to know the progress made by the server on the Invoice Generation process.

But, here comes the actual problem, the server may not respond to the same application domain, and tell about the progress made, before completing the earlier requested process of Invoice Generation. Or else, it may break the earlier process.

Can it be done using multiple threads? Or may be some other methodology of .NET.

My application is in ASP.NET with C# and answers with Code examples or references will appreciated.

Comment: I am interested what kind of calculations are those which take more than 30 seconds on a server?

Comment: Basically, the whole process can be thought as being a Batch of Processes. Its like preparing invoices of 3000 sales made during a month. As there are multiple tables in the database and there can be a number of attributes related to a sale, so I am quite sure, the process will take more than few minutes.

Comment: I that case i think you need to optimize your architecture as few minutes for 3000 sales is not normal. The average computer makes about 2 000 000 000 - 4 000 000 000 calculations per second